# VBA AutoFill adjacent dynamic column results in error?

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, autofill

I am trying to AutoFill dynamic and adjacent column but I'm getting an error. Tried lots of tips but nothing works. Would appreciate the help

```
Dim Column As Integer
Column = Workbooks("Outbound Month").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count + 1

Workbooks("Outbound Month").Worksheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("W1:W39").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(Cells(1, Column), Cells(39, Column)), Type:=xlFillDefault)
```

Comment: Describe an error, please.

Answer (score 1):

## Adjacent vs Last Column

Your `AutoFill` isn't doing anything so I've used just `Copy`.

### Adjacent

Adjacent to the right **ALWAYS** means the next right column which would be column `X` in this case.

```
Sub AdjacentToTheRightColumn()

  Const cWBName As String = "Outbound Month"
  Const cWsName As String = "Summary"
  Const cRange As String = "W1:W39"

  With Workbooks(cWBName).Worksheets(cWsName)
    .Range(cRange).Copy .Range(cRange).Offset(0, 1)
  End With

End Sub
```

### After Last

After last column **ONLY** means column `X`, **IF** `W` is last column.

```
Sub AfterLastColumn()

  Const cWBName As String = "Outbound Month"
  Const cWsName As String = "Summary"
  Const cRange As String = "W1:W39"

  Dim LastColumn As Integer

  With Workbooks(cWBName).Worksheets(cWsName)
      LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      .Range(cRange).Copy .Range(cRange) _
          .Offset(0, LastColumn - Range(cRange).Column + 1)
    End With

End Sub
```